# Using Multiple Select or JOIN ON to add a column response in the fetched array

Tags: php, mysql, join, multi-select

I've tried multiple answers on stackoverflow and I can't seem to find an adequate solution to my problem. The current query I'm trying right now is:

```
SELECT (
SELECT * FROM mds_media
) AS m
(
SELECT video_id FROM mds_featured WHERE video_id = m.id
) AS f

ORDER BY f.video_id DESC, m.id DESC
```

I've also tried JOINing

```
SELECT mds_media.*, mds_featured.* FROM mds_media AS m
JOIN mds_featured 
ON mds_featured.video_id = m.id
ORDER BY mds_featured.video_id DESC, mds_media.id DESC
```

The only thing I want to do is have mds_featured column video_id attach to the overall result if it is the id of the found media. So my mysql_fetch_array() for example outputs:

array(id,name,blah,blah,blah,video_id) //Of course containing values
//IF mds_featured has a row present with the same value as id from mds_media in it's video_id column

or

array(id,name,blah,blah,blah)
//IF mds_featured.video_id does NOT have a row present with mds_media.id

Appreciate any suggestions/helpful tips in providing a solution. Either I am not reading correctly, or I'm messing up somewhere and the answers I see aren't helping me. Sorry if I could of already solved this and haven't with the provided solutions.

I don't plan on altering my database table to have a column containing featured/video_id, as there is a reason the table is separate.

---

Updated working code for future reference for others:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, mds_featured.video_id 
FROM mds_media m 
LEFT JOIN mds_featured 
ON mds_featured.video_id = m.id 
ORDER BY mds_featured.video_id DESC, m.id DESC
```

Thanks to Vatev

Comment: You can't have a result set with a different number of columns per row. A `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to get all the records from mds_media with some NULL's in the non-featured ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that first, and successfully, however my id column is disappearing. Both tables have an id column. Let me rehash: Anything NOT featured has no id column.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe you should not select `*` from both?

Comment: Derp, You're right! Thanks Vatev.

Updated working code for future reference for others:

   SELECT m.id, m.name, mds_featured.video_id FROM mds_media m
   LEFT JOIN mds_featured
   ON mds_featured.video_id = m.id
   ORDER BY mds_featured.video_id DESC, m.id DESC

Answer (score 0):

Change your JOIN to a LEFT JOIN. That will give you all rows from mds_media matched up with any that match from mds_featured. When there is no match, the mds_featured columns will be null.

```
SELECT mds_media.*, mds_featured.* 
FROM mds_media AS m
LEFT JOIN mds_featured 
ON mds_featured.video_id = m.id
ORDER BY mds_featured.video_id DESC, mds_media.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks :) Vatev was a little faster, but both responses were correct. I just wasn't using LEFT JOIN properly.